# Restrict notification alerts in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, azure-mobile-services, remote-notifications

I am receiving remote notifications from Azure Notification hub in my iOS app. Notification are sent with different type like:

1.

```
{ "aps":
    {"message":"You got one new message"}
}
```

2.

```
{ "aps": 
    {"geoData":"Dubai, UAE"}
}
```

I want to restrict notification alerts to "type 1" only as I don't need to alert users about `geoData` notifications. Can someone help me?

Comment: you can do that on your azure only, system is taking care of notifications, you don't have access to them before you open app

Comment: @Zahid Usman Cheema use group  for notifications which provider using ? provider must be give notification group codes.

Comment: sure. There is something called notification tag on azure. we can add a tag with a notification. I think that may help.

Comment: I have no user groups. I need to send both notification to all users but notify for type 1 only as type 2 notifications will be used to update location on Map.

Comment: You can send a silent notification through Notification Hubs and simply not display it on your client. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-push-apple-apns-secure-notification for an application of silent notifications.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.